# Remove vertical space before bullet point multicol

Tags: multicol, bullets

I am trying to make two columns of bullet points, but it is adding extra space after the title.

```
\section{Test bullets}\vspace{-1.5em}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test1 --- A, B, C
\item Test 2 --- Ay, Bee, Cee
\item Test-3 ---  A
\item Test Four --- B
\item Test-Five ---  C
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

Here are all the possibly relevant parts of my setup:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}
{\fontsize{15}{25}\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}[\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\section}
{0em}{1em}{0.8em}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0em}{2em}{0.85em}
```

All the other sections are spaced fine, but this one isn't. In the second column, it also skips a space for a bullet for some reason.

Here is a picture:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [tasks](https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks?lang=en) package for multicolumn lists? It usually works better than `itemize`

Comment: @AlanXiang Would you mind giving an example please?

Comment: You can click the link and open the documentation. There are examples on  page 3-4.

Comment: @AlanXiang How do I get it? `\usepackage{tasks}` doesn't work

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? I suppose it's MikTeX because TeXLive usually ships with this package. In MikTeX, you probably need to add this package in your package manager.